# Blackberry MDS Simulator installation problem

Tags: blackberry, simulator, bb-messenger

I'm developing an app that needs to send something via BBM, so I wanted to try it out.

The problem is I can't get the BBM simulator to run.

I followed the instructions found on the [Blackberry Messenger](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/blackberrymessenger/) page but when I execute run.bat it says the following:

```
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.530 PYT>:[0]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SCM, Admin. Task- H
TTP Proxy Mappings>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.538 PYT>:[1]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SCM, Admin. Task- r
efresh media management>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.577 PYT>:[2]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SCM, The push servi
ce is ready to receive requests>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.635 PYT>:[3]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = J2SE 1
.7.0 Charsets supported:Big5,Big5-HKSCS,EUC-JP,EUC-KR,GB18030,GB2312,GBK,IBM-Tha
i,IBM00858,IBM01140,IBM01141,IBM01142,IBM01143,IBM01144,IBM01145,IBM01146,IBM011
47,IBM01148,IBM01149,IBM037,IBM1026,IBM1047,IBM273,IBM277,IBM278,IBM280,IBM284,I
BM285,IBM297,IBM420,IBM424,IBM437,IBM500,IBM775,IBM850,IBM852,IBM855,IBM857,IBM8
60,IBM861,IBM862,IBM863,IBM864,IBM865,IBM866,IBM868,IBM869,IBM870,IBM871,IBM918,
ISO-2022-CN,ISO-2022-JP,ISO-2022-JP-2,ISO-2022-KR,ISO-8859-1,ISO-8859-13,ISO-885
9-15,ISO-8859-2,ISO-8859-3,ISO-8859-4,ISO-8859-5,ISO-8859-6,ISO-8859-7,ISO-8859-
8,ISO-8859-9,JIS_X0201,JIS_X0212-1990,KOI8-R,KOI8-U,Shift_JIS,TIS-620,US-ASCII,U
TF-16,UTF-16BE,UTF-16LE,UTF-32,UTF-32BE,UTF-32LE,UTF-8,windows-1250,windows-1251
,windows-1252,windows-1253,windows-1254,windows-1255,windows-1256,windows-1257,w
indows-1258,windows-31j,x-Big5-HKSCS-2001,x-Big5-Solaris,x-euc-jp-linux,x-EUC-TW
,x-eucJP-Open,x-IBM1006,x-IBM1025,x-IBM1046,x-IBM1097,x-IBM1098,x-IBM1112,x-IBM1
122,x-IBM1123,x-IBM1124,x-IBM1364,x-IBM1381,x-IBM1383,x-IBM33722,x-IBM737,x-IBM8
33,x-IBM834,x-IBM856,x-IBM874,x-IBM875,x-IBM921,x-IBM922,x-IBM930,x-IBM933,x-IBM
935,x-IBM937,x-IBM939,x-IBM942,x-IBM942C,x-IBM943,x-IBM943C,x-IBM948,x-IBM949,x-
IBM949C,x-IBM950,x-IBM964,x-IBM970,x-ISCII91,x-ISO-2022-CN-CNS,x-ISO-2022-CN-GB,
x-iso-8859-11,x-JIS0208,x-JISAutoDetect,x-Johab,x-MacArabic,x-MacCentralEurope,x
-MacCroatian,x-MacCyrillic,x-MacDingbat,x-MacGreek,x-MacHebrew,x-MacIceland,x-Ma
cRoman,x-MacRomania,x-MacSymbol,x-MacThai,x-MacTurkish,x-MacUkraine,x-MS932_0213
,x-MS950-HKSCS,x-MS950-HKSCS-XP,x-mswin-936,x-PCK,x-SJIS_0213,x-UTF-16LE-BOM,X-U
TF-32BE-BOM,X-UTF-32LE-BOM,x-windows-50220,x-windows-50221,x-windows-874,x-windo
ws-949,x-windows-950,x-windows-iso2022jp>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.637 PYT>:[4]:<BBM_MDS>:<INFO >:<LAYER = SCM, DefaultJobPool
 Pool size = 10>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.638 PYT>:[5]:<BBM_MDS>:<INFO >:<LAYER = SCM, DefaultJobPool
 Queue length = 20>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.639 PYT>:[6]:<BBM_MDS>:<INFO >:<LAYER = SCM, maxMem: 518979
584 maxPoolSize: 10>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.653 PYT>:[7]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Connec
ted, TOPSERVICE = KEYNEGO, LOWERSERVICE = GME>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.654 PYT>:[8]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Connec
ted, TOPSERVICE = SERVICE_BOOK, LOWERSERVICE = GME>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.655 PYT>:[9]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Connec
ted, TOPSERVICE = SRPH, LOWERSERVICE = GME>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.656 PYT>:[10]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Conne
cted, TOPSERVICE = CMIME, LOWERSERVICE = GME>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.657 PYT>:[11]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Conne
cted, TOPSERVICE = RIM_IM, LOWERSERVICE = GME>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.658 PYT>:[12]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Conne
cted, TOPSERVICE = IPPP, LOWERSERVICE = GME>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.659 PYT>:[13]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Conne
cted, TOPSERVICE = GME, LOWERSERVICE = MDP>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.660 PYT>:[14]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Conne
cted, TOPSERVICE = REG, LOWERSERVICE = MDP>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.661 PYT>:[15]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Conne
cted, TOPSERVICE = MDP, LOWERSERVICE = GPAK>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.662 PYT>:[16]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Conne
cted, TOPSERVICE = GPAK, LOWERSERVICE = UDP>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.674 PYT>:[17]:<BBM_MDS>:<EVENT>:<LAYER = SCM, BBM MDS_START
MDS; >
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.676 PYT>:[18]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SRPH, LAYER = SRPH
, EVENT = Initialization>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.699 PYT>:[19]:<BBM_MDS>:<INFO >:<maxMem: 518979584 maxQueue
Size: 250>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.701 PYT>:[20]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SRPH, LAYER = SRPH
, EVENT = Started>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.702 PYT>:[21]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SRPH, EVENT = Star
ted, THREAD = SRPHprotocolMainThread>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.703 PYT>:[22]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SRPH, EVENT = Star
ted, THREAD = SRPHListenOnDatagramStatus>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.705 PYT>:[23]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SRPH, EVENT = Star
ted, THREAD = SRPHListenForClientsPackets>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.705 PYT>:[24]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SRPH, EVENT = Star
ted, THREAD = SRPHQueuesManager>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.708 PYT>:[25]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SB, EVENT = Starte
d, THREAD = ListenOnDatagramStatus>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.708 PYT>:[26]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = SB, EVENT = Starte
d, THREAD = ListenForClientsStatus>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.709 PYT>:[27]:<BBM_MDS>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = BBM, EVENT = Initi
alization>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.737 PYT>:[28]:<BBM_MDS>:<INFO >:<LAYER = SCM, BBMSessionJob
Pool Pool size = 10>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.737 PYT>:[29]:<BBM_MDS>:<INFO >:<LAYER = SCM, BBMSessionJob
Pool Queue length = 20>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.739 PYT>:[30]:<BBM_MDS>:<INFO >:<LAYER = SCM, BBMSessionJob
Pool Queue length = 1280>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.789 PYT>:[31]:<BBM_MDS>:<ERROR>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Excep
tion, net.rim.application.ipproxyservice.b.a: Initialize failed>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.789 PYT>:[31]:<BBM_MDS>:<ERROR>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Excep
tion,   at net.rim.application.ipproxyservice.IPProxyServiceApplication.start(Un
known Source)>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.789 PYT>:[31]:<BBM_MDS>:<ERROR>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Excep
tion,   at net.rim.application.ipproxyservice.IPProxyServiceApplication.main(Unk
nown Source)>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.789 PYT>:[31]:<BBM_MDS>:<ERROR>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Excep
tion, Caused by: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.SecurityExc
eption>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.789 PYT>:[31]:<BBM_MDS>:<ERROR>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Excep
tion,   at net.rim.protocol.bbm.BBMProtocol.initialize(Unknown Source)>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.789 PYT>:[31]:<BBM_MDS>:<ERROR>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Excep
tion,   at net.rim.protocol.bbm.BBMProtocol.start(Unknown Source)>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.789 PYT>:[31]:<BBM_MDS>:<ERROR>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Excep
tion,   at net.rim.service.c.start(Unknown Source)>
<2011-09-01 23:26:08.789 PYT>:[31]:<BBM_MDS>:<ERROR>:<LAYER = SCM, EVENT = Excep
tion,   ... 2 more>
```

- Java SE Development Kit 7 installed: C:\jdk1.7.0\
- Java JRE installed: C:\jdk1.7.0\jre7\

(Note that there is another jre folder: C:\jdk1.7.0\jre)

JAVA_HOME variable points to: C:\jdk1.7.0\
Added "C:\jdk1.7.0\bin\;" to the front of path variable.
Copied files local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar to both

1) C:\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\security ; and

2) C:\jdk1.7.0\jre7\lib\security

(I first copied them only to C:\jdk1.7.0\jre7\lib\security but it said "Did you install Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files?")

I downloaded the SDK, extracted the contents to "C:\BBM\", got into MDS Simulator and extracted the contents right there as well.

Running Windows 7 64 bits.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

The BBM SDK does work with Java 7 JDK x86 on Windows x64.

But if you install Java 7, then you must install "Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 7" from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html , and not version 6 of the JCE files as per the instructions.

Extract the contents of this zip, then copy the extracted policy files to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\jre\lib\security

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

- BBM must work on java 32bits and not 64. I was mentioned in install documentation
- Not sure about java 7.